# Why the http get is not reaching the server?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose

I want to get just one document from Mongodb collection, I am using Angular 8 on the front-end and Node js for the server, so when I request the specific url to get the data, Angular seems to do the request but the server does not respond. I tried to do a console log on the server side to verify if the request is reached but the console log is never printed.

**This is the code for the function on the Angular typescript file:**

```
  searchUser(value) {
    if (this.query !== '' && this.query.length > 0) {
      this.ps.search(value);   //ps is the service
    } else {
      console.log('Incorrect');
    }
  }
```

**This is the code in the Service file:**

```
  search(value) {

    return this
    .http
    .get(`${this.uri}/searchUser/${value}`);

  }
```

**This is the Node get request function:**

```
app.get('/searchUser/:value', function (req, res) {
    let value = req.params.value;

    console.log(value + ' <<< value in the server');

    user.find({ user: value}, function(err, doc) {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);  
        }else {
            // res.json(res);
            console.log(doc);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: You must subscribe to the observable return from `search`. `this.ps.search(value).subscribe((val) =>....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `subscribe` to it.

```
 searchUser(value) {
        if (this.query !== '' && this.query.length > 0) {
          this.ps.search(value).subscribe();   //ps is the service
        } else {
          console.log('Incorrect');
        }
      }
```

You just not triggering an observable that are returned from your service.

Comment: Or better yet, let your HTML manage the subscription by binding it to the `AsyncPipe`. Makes sure you don't accidentally introduce a memory leak in your application.